# In case: How to use it correctly in the following sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

> 1) He was expecting a delivery, so he stayed at home **in case it arrived**.

In the above sentence, I feel some connectivity is missing between "so he stayed at home" and "in case it arrived" and there should be some words between the 2 double quoted phrases.

> 2) He was expecting a delivery, so he stayed at home **as it could arrive**.

The above sentence is something I prefer to use.

So, I need to know if I'
m wrong in constructing the 2nd sentence. I want some clarity on the 1st sentence as well.

Comment: Not an answer, but _He was expecting a delivery, so he stayed at home_ would be fine. The addition of his expectation of the delivery arriving is redundant, because that is what _expecting a delivery_ means.

Comment: @oerkelens  I understand it. But, is the 1st sentence grammatically correct? I am more concerned about "so he stayed at home in case it arrived"

Comment: The first sentence is good, idiomatic English just as it would be spoken or written by a native speaker. Please tell us why you prefer the second sentence.

Comment: @P. E. Dant I am using "as" here to connect 2 clauses unlike the first one.

Answer (score 1):

"In case" means "to allow for the possibility that" ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_case#English)).

I would say the first sentence is both more natural and more exact, which is a good combination. One uses  "in case" to talk about a possible outcome.

It's certainly possible for "as", "since", or "because" to work alongside the conditional "could" as you used it. But these are all general-purpose ways to indicate causation. That is, they don't make the relationship between the cause and the result explicit.

But "in case" is well-suited to this job: Your subject wants to be prepared for event X, so he does Y *in case* X happens. No further explanation is needed. There's something satisfying about that.

Here are some more typical uses of "in case":

> We should make sure our car windows are rolled up in case it rains overnight.
>
> Take your phone in case you need to reach us.
>
> I applied to three other graduate programs in case I get rejected from my first choice.